# RXJS - How to use the result of 2 different observable as parameters for a function call

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I've 2 observables (async). 
The first one returns an array of status with a rank for each status.
The second one returns an array of users with the status of each user.

I'm trying to output a user list sorted by status.

This is what I've tried :

```
const sortedUserList$: Subject<any> = new Subject();
this.getStatusList()
  .pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe(statusList=> {
    this.getUserList()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(userList=> {
        // ... sorting algo using both statusList and userList
        sortedUserList$.next(centersPlanning);
      });
  });
```

Obviously, it doesn't work because `statusList` isn't available in the second `subscribe` because it's out of its scope.

It's also doesn't look like nesting two `subscribte` this way is the right way of doing things using rxJS.

I've also tried using `mergeMap` but with no more sucess.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Have a look at `forkJoin`, `combineLatest`, `zip` or `withLatestFrom`.

Comment: Thanks! `combineLatest` was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `forkJoin` from rxjs. Try something like this:

```
import { forkJoin, of, Subject } from 'rxjs'
import {take, delay} from 'rxjs/operators'



sortedUserList: Subject<any> = new Subject();

//For demonstration purposes
getStatusList() {
    return of('first').pipe(
        delay(2000)
    );
}

//For demonstration purposes
getUserList() {
    return of('second').pipe(
        delay(1000)
    )
}

ngOnInit() {
    forkJoin(
        this.getStatusList(),
        this.getUserList()
    ).pipe(
        take(1)
    ).subscribe(resp => {
        console.log(resp) // ['first', 'second']
        //Do whatever you want with both responses here.
        this.sortedUserList$.next(centersPlanning)
    })
}
```

Check it [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mwezgv?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts/)